# How do I make a Lightning Web Component reload, not just refresh?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

I have a Lightning Web Component that contains a chart using Chartjs.  However, when the dataset changes, the new chart is appended instead of refreshing the existing chart.  One method that I think COULD work would be to force the component to completely reload every time the dataset would change instead of just refreshing.  That would wipe out the existing chart and load a new one instead.

However, I cannot figure out how to force my component to completely refresh - is there a way to do it?

All help gratefully received.

Note: All details mentioned in [Is there a way to refresh chart data in a Lightning Web Component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305113/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-chart-data-in-a-lightning-web-component)

Comment: If you wired your data from apex to your component try to use refreshApex which will refresh your dataset and since it is wired change will directly be reflected in your component.

Comment: @MertYALTI This is related to a previous question about ChartJS not clearing out the old chart. See this user's question history for more info.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely related to that question - I have been trying to find any possible way to make it happen, and came up with this related question.  The issue is that refreshing the data in the component is refreshing my component, but is not RELOADING it.

Comment: recreating this use case would take a lot of time. can you create a playground and share here?

Comment: The problem is that it involves data retrieval using APEX.  I can try to set it up without that, but the question is more of a paradigm one.  Can you set a LWC to reload completely instead of just re-rendering when an event fires that the LWC is subscribed to?